# Firestore & Node.js: .set/.update => pass a variable as key

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a variable `var key = "Something"` and want to set a document using this variable as the key.
When I'm trying to do it using `settings_ref.update({key: false});` this is obviously using "key" as a string itself.

How can I use a variable as the key of the new data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the bracket notation:

```
var obj = {};
obj[key] = false;
settings_ref.update(obj);
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors